# Issues running a python script with Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am new to spark and just wanted to check on a problem that i am facing. My objective was to read a nested xml file, flatten it out and save it as a csv file. I wrote the code. It works really fine in pyspark in my cluster. When i write the code line by line in pyspark i can see the executors from different nodes being assigned the worker processes. Now the problem is that when i run the same code as a python script, the executors from different nodes are not allotted. The worker process starts on the node i am running the script on and does not get parallelized. Consequently it is taking much longer time to do the processing. I am attaching the screenshot of the warning with this post.

Has anyone faced it as well? Thank you in anticipation.
Also i dont own this cluster but i am working on it for someone. So i have no idea about how many nodes are there.

[image]

Comment: check Spark Properties and change parameters(limit resources) so you can allocate less resources or limit them. also how do you run it ? what parameters are provided ? this is an example ./bin/spark-submit \
  --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi \
  --master mesos://207.184.161.138:7077 \
  --deploy-mode cluster
  --supervise
  --executor-memory 20G \
  --total-executor-cores 100 \
  http://path/to/examples.jar \
  1000

Comment: Right now i am running it as: 
spark-submit --packages com.databricks:spark-xml_2.10:0.3.3 csv-script.py

I tried running it with --master yarn-cluster argument but that just goes on printing this message indefnitely <INFO CLIENT: application report for application_(same number) (state: Accepted)>

This is a cloudera environment with 50+ nodes but i am not sure how many of them leverage spark. When i was running my code in the pyspark shell About 19 executors were being created every time. Also how do you determine the executor memory and the cores? Is it the RAM and the CPU count?

Comment: You'll need to specify resources allocation, each app does have diferent ones and this can solve the issue.

Comment: I updated the previous comment to include more info

Comment: spark-submit --packages com.databricks:spark-xml_2.10:0.3.3 --master mesos://host:5050 --executor-memory 10g --driver-memory 10g csv-script.py , you can add more flags. Without knowing details of the cluster and configuration is hard to set all the flags and debug ... try to run as stand alone in the cluster and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

I did get it working. I was not initializing the configuration properly.
I had specified setmaster to local in the spark configuration.
I just removed that property tag and the app started distributing across the available executors even while running the script.